# How much will macOS High Sierra upgrade cost me?

Tags: macos, mac

I have a Mac running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5. unfortunately I am not very good at installing new programmes on my computer, and I want to update mine to the latest release macOS High Sierra.

What will it cost me if I go the the Mac shop at the Metro centre to have it installed?

Comment: It won't cost you anything if you take it to the Apple Store, there's one at Gateshead, if that's the Metro Centre you mean. https://www.apple.com/uk/retail/metrocentre/

Comment: Please edit your question, or add into a comment, the model of Macintosh you are using. Depending on its vintage, it may not be able to run High Sierra.

Comment: macOS Updates have been free for years and will most likely continue to be that way.

Comment: OS X 10.9 Mavericks was the first release to be offered for free. All the subsequent major releases have followed the tradition since then.

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need to check the compatibility of your Mac with the subsequently released version(s) of macOS. You can refer to the support document from Apple, [Use the Mac operating system that came with your Mac, or a compatible newer version](https://support.apple.com/HT201686). This will help you in determining if your Mac can run macOS High Sierra (if not than what is the latest released supported by your Mac). Specifically, to check if your Mac can run macOS High Sierra, check if your model of Mac is listed under **Can your Mac use High Sierra?** section in the document, [How to download macOS High Sierra](https://support.apple.com/HT201475).

As mentioned, you are already running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.5. All the subsequent releases of OS X (later re-branded as macOS starting with macOS Sierra 10.12) are released by Apple **free of cost** and can be easily downloaded using the Mac App Store available on your Mac.

If you can visit an [Apple Retail store](https://www.apple.com/retail/), you should be able get assistance with upgradation to the latest supported release for free. If you do not have one in vicinity, you can also check with an authorised Apple retailer and check for the pricing. There are **no costs** from Apple whatsoever for upgradation (in your case).

Comment: Thank you very much Nimash for answering my question I will take it to the Metro at Gateshead to have it done. ~Thanks again Ian.

Comment: @IanRawson You are welcome. To show that an answer worked for you on this site, you upvote and accept it. This also helps other having similar problem.